# Convert package variable of type System.Object to a List<String> with SSIS C# Script

Tags: c#, ssis, dts

my question is simple yet the headache I get from it is quite serious. In a SSIS package, how can I convert a System.Object package variable at run time  into a list of strings with a C# script so I can then select the Max value from this list and assign back to another package variable.

(Details:)
In SSIS i have a preceding Cozy Roc task which gets the list of file names from a remote SFTP directory and saves it into a local (package) variable "FilesNamesList" of type System.Object. What I would like to do with a C# script task is to parse this object variable into a list so I can then select the Max Value/File Name and assign it to another package variable "LastFileName" of type string. I will then use this second variable to download only the file with this name thru SFTP. Here is the non_working code.

```
    String myString;
    List<String> myList;
    var myVariable = Dts.Variables["User::FileNamesList"];
    myList = myVariable as List<String>; //Main Challenge
    myString = myList.Max();
    Dts.Variables.["User::LastFileName"] = myString;
```

Second option I am trying with is to extract into a table object but I still get an error trying to fill the table:

```
    OleDbDataAdapter A = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    A.Fill(dt, Dts.Variables["User::pkg_FileList"].Value); //Error
    List<string> myValues = new List<string>();
```

Comment: Which line gives you the error?

Comment: Richard's suggestion was that instantiating the variable in a separate task would force it to be a list but it doesn't work for me even though this doesn't throw an error - Dts.Variables["User::pkg_FileList"].Value = new List<String>();

Comment: What I am trying now is this (extract into a table) but I get an error when trying to "fill" the table object.                  OleDbDataAdapter A = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            A.Fill(dt, Dts.Variables["User::pkg_FileList"].Value); //Error
            List<string> myValues = new List<string>();

Comment: What type is the `User::FileNamesList` variable? If you aren't sure, just throw an error in the script `throw new Exception(Dts.Variables["User::FileNamesList"].GetType().Name)` - this will get you the type name - maybe it's just a string array and not a list object? There's no cast to `List<String>` from `string[]` but you can `var list = new List<string>(); list.AddRange(stringArray);`

Comment: Can you capture Dts.Variables["User::pkg_FileList"].Value as a string? If so, what is the string's value?

Comment: Dts.Variables["User::FileNamesList"].GetType().Name --returns "Variable"

Comment: Dts.Variables["User::FileNamesList"].Value.ToString() -- returns "System.Object[]"

Answer (score 1):

IN SSIS you have to grab the variable into an object variable, then convert to list like this:

```
Object ObjFileNamesList= Dts.Variables["User::FileNamesList"].Value;
List<string> lstFileNamesList = (List<string>)ObjFileNamesList;

// then do your list logic here
```

Comment: If the OP has already tried a cast here: `myList = myVariable as List<String>;` why would this explicit cast work any different?

Comment: I do not remember why but I had similar issue using the var instead of Object.  I think it may be because the SSIS variable type is an object.  I can not remember exactly why though

Comment: Yeah but using `var` just tells the compiler to infer the variable type, it will just be whatever type the object that's assigned to it is. In this case probably `Object` since you can stuff whatever type you want inside the package variables.

Comment: True, but I remember having some issue doing that inside SSIS (it worked fine not in SSIS, but when I moved it to SSIS I had to update to the above)

Comment: The preceding Cozy Roc task which gets the File Name List requires that it writes into a System.Object variable or it won't work. The way I understand is that System.Object is a very complex and general object and it can store anything including an array of tables so there should be some way to cast it using a logic like "Get the first array in System.Object and then loop through that to get each individual value" and build a list that way.